# What happened to the BBC Atlantis TV Show?

Tags: production, atlantis-series

This series was really interesting,  but the Season Two finale left me expecting a new season.

Later, I found that the TV show was stopped.

So is there any possibility of season 3 release?

Comment: Title and body ask different questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantis_(TV_series)#Broadcast):

> On 4 October 2014, the first teaser trailer for the second series was released, followed by the first official trailer on 29 October 2014. It premiered on 15 November 2014.
>
> In January 2015, the BBC confirmed that a new series was not to be commissioned, and on 16 May 2015, the series ended.

Also according to [this](https://tvseriesfinale.com/tv-show/atlantis-cancelled-no-season-three-for-bbc-tv-show-35441/) website:

> BBC announced the show’s cancellation this way: “The final seven episodes of Atlantis will transmit on BBC One in spring. We would like to thank Urban Myth Films and all the cast and crew but the series will not be re-commissioned. We are very proud of both series but to keep increasing the range of BBC One drama we have to make difficult decisions to bring new shows through.”

So no, 5 years later they're not going to produce a 3rd season.